# Ajax Form data isn't sending anything to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i'm trying to send over image data to php when an image is selected for upload by using ajax.

i've tried sending data to php without ajax and it seems to work properly and i am able to do stuff with the file data. however because i don't want the php to reload to a different page i want to use ajax.

so i've sort of come to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the ajax call or formdata.

I've got no clue as to why its not working.

Any suggestions

Jquery:

```js
$( document ).on('click','#upload_img_btn', function(){
  $('#choose_img').click();

  form_data = new FormData();
  $("#choose_img").change(function(){
    var selected_img = this.files[0];
    form_data.append("#choose_img", selected_img);
    $.ajax({
        url: $("#img_uploader").attr("action"),
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(validation){
          if (validation == "success") {
             readURL(this);
          } else {
            alert(validation);
          }
        }
    });
  });

});

function readURL(input) {
       if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
           var reader = new FileReader();

           reader.onload = function (e) {
             var img_preview = '<img id="preview" src="'+ e.target.result +'" />' +
             '<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" id="post_img">'
             $('.rounded_box').replaceWith(img_preview);
           }

           reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
   }
```

PHP

```html
<?php


echo  $_FILES['choose_img']['name'];


?>
```

Comment: Your `Upload` button doesn't seems to be making upload request to server. is it same in code or just typo while posting.

Comment: Hey sorry i forgot to add the jquery code. i've created a custom button and hidden the select one but making the custom button click the select on when it is clicked. ill add it to the question. so the image preview actually works but php is not responding that's all

Answer (score 0):

In your JS, you're never actually sending the file to the server and getting the output. You're doing all the logic on the client, and never doing validation.

If you wanted to validate the file **before submitting the form**, you have two options:

1. Server side: You'd need to do an ajax request with the image, and get the output from the server, and display it (maybe using `alert`)
2. Client side: You can check if the file is an image in your JS code

Comment: so if i was to do an ajax request how would i pass on the image data to php validation when a file is selected instead of after being submitted to upload?

Comment: Read around the web, you'll find plenty of information. Personally, I think it's a bit of a pain- I'd validate it once client side before previewing the image, and then again when you actually submit the form.

Comment: Is there an advantage on server side compared to client? like is it more secure on the server side?

Comment: If you check the image on submission of the form (before, say, putting it in your db), then there's no downside at all to doing the original check (before the preview) client side